# How can I map a foreign key ID column (property) in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, foreign-keys

I have a question about how to map a foreign key ID with NHibernate mapping file. eg. I have the following classes:

```
class Topic {
  public long ID {get; set;}  
  public string Name {get; set;}  
}  

class Post {  
  public long ID {get; set;}  
  public string Title {get; set;}  
  public string Content {get; set;}  
  public long TopicID {get; set;} // This is the FK refers to the Topic entity
}
```

The Post entity doesn't reference the Topic directly, it only references the Topic by the TopicID as show above. However seems that NHibernate `<many-to-one`> mapping will only map the Topic as an entity in the Post, but I what I want is the TopicID FK, not the Topic entity. Could anybody help me on this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just declare the TopicID as a property, and not a `many-to-one`.

```xml
<property name="TopicID" column="TopicID" type="Int64" />
```

Comment: But how to create the constraint between this TopicID property and the ID of the Topic?

Comment: @daxnet - Why is it important for nHibernate to be aware of the constraint? There should be a foreign key constraint in the database, so your application is still safe from corrupted data.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a property in your Post mapping that contains the value of the TopicID field, then just map it as a simple property:

```
<property name="TopicID" column="TopicID" type="long" />
```

If you want it mapped as an object, then use a many-to-one mapping:

```
<many-to-one name="Topic" column="TopicID" class="Topic"  />
```

Comment: Yes, I was also aware of this, but if I use with property instead of the `<many-to-one>`, how could the DB tables be constrainted by the foreign keys? I mean how to make NH Schema Tools to create a FK constraint when working with this property approach? -- Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that you should be able to first create the mapping file with the <many-to-one> mapping and use that to create the database schema with the foreign key reference.  Once the database schema is created, you can just change the mapping to have a simple property, if that is what you want in your domain model.